# I want to use %timeit, but don't know how to do it

Tags: python, timeit

First, I'm still really new to Python. I've seen some examples that use %timeit and it looks really useful for doing some optimization work. The problem is, I haven't found how to actually get started with it. It looks like there's some similar ways to do this and I found some Python 2.7 examples too. Okay, so here's some easy points for a Python Guru out there.

I'm using Python 3.6.

What do I need to import? Either import syntax is fine.

```
import xxxxx    or    from xxxxx import yyyyy
```

It looks like I can use %timeit on loops and some other constructs. Can they be used on "def" too?

I'm fine if you drop me a link and say "RTFM," it will at least get me going in the right direction.

Comment: if you're new to Python (or programming in general) I would greatly advise you against using anything related to the optimization.[Premature optimization is root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%timeit` is `ipython` magic; you can only use it by [installing IPython](https://ipython.org/) and using it as your interactive interpreter instead of plain `python`. It's built on top of [the `timeit` module's `timeit.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.repeat) (possibly reimplemented; it does some extra work to make the results more useful to humans at a glance), which you can use in regular Python, but `%timeit`'s convenience requires `ipython`.

Comment: This looks amazing. So, I am trying to go the route of adding "ipython==6.2.0" to my requirements.txt file. It installs fine. I can even do "import timeit". But I still run into problems using "%timeit" and "timeit".

Rereading you answer, makes me think I can't use IntelliJ with it, since it uses the "Python plugin".

Comment: @NickAllen: `import timeit` is unrelated; the `timeit` *module* ships with plain Python. Odds are IntelliJ is running a plain Python interpreter, not the `ipython` executable. `ipython` is much more than just a few libraries, it's a complete wrapper that replaces the interactive Python shell; you need to run `ipython` itself to get the magic features, merely having the libraries installed is insufficient.

Comment: Thanks for your time and insightfulness. I really appreciate it.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/ipython.html for instructions on how to setup PyCharm with ipython